# Complete compactness and retract

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, limits-colimits

**Defn**: Let $\mathsf{C}$ be a locally small category which admits all small colimits. We say that $X \in \mathsf{C}$ is **completely compact**  if the functor $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{C}}(X, \cdot): \mathsf{C} \rightarrow \mathsf{Set}$ preserves all *small* colimits.

Note that this is DIFFERENT from calling an object "compact", when we only required that $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{C}}(X, \cdot)$ preserves *filtered* colimits.

Let $\mathsf{C}$ be a category. A **retract** of an object $X \in \mathsf{C}$ is a tuple $(i,r,Y)$, where the composition
$$
Y \xrightarrow{i} X \xrightarrow{r} Y
$$
is $\mathrm{id}_Y$. We also say that $Y$ is a retract of $X$. We have the following fact for retracts:

> **FACT**: $Y$ is both the equalizer and the coequalizer of the diagram
> $$
> X {{{i \circ r} \atop \longrightarrow}\atop{\longrightarrow \atop {\mathrm{id}_X}}} X.
> $$

**My question**: How to show that if $X \in \mathsf{C}$ is completely compact, then any retract of $X$ is completely compact?

**My attempts**: Some discussions have been in the post
[Why is a direct summand of a compact object compact?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2913974/why-is-a-direct-summand-of-a-compact-object-compact/2913997#2913997) . Yet people only dealt with the **compact** case, but not **completely compact** case. In the compact case, we can prove the similar statement (replacing *completely compact* by *compact* everywhere) as follows:

Let $\alpha: \mathsf{I} \rightarrow \mathsf{C}$ be a functor (i.e. a diagram in $\mathsf{C}$), where $\mathsf{I}$ is **filtered**, then with the listed fact above, we have
\begin{align}
\varinjlim_{i \in \mathsf{I}} \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{C}}(Y, \alpha(i)) &= \varinjlim_{i \in \mathsf{I}} \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{C}}\left(\varinjlim_{j \in \mathsf{J} := \{0,1\} } X, \alpha(i)\right) \\
&= \varinjlim_{i \in \mathsf{I}} \varprojlim_{j \in \mathsf{J} := \{0,1\} } \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{C}}( X, \alpha(i)) \\
&\cong \varprojlim_{j \in \mathsf{J} := \{0,1\} } \varinjlim_{i \in \mathsf{I}}  \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{C}}( X, \alpha(i)) \\
&\cong \varprojlim_{j \in \mathsf{J} := \{0,1\} }   \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{C}}( X, \varinjlim_{i \in \mathsf{I}} \alpha(i)) \\
&\cong \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{C}}\left(\varinjlim_{j \in \mathsf{J} := \{0,1\} } X, \varinjlim_{i \in \mathsf{I}} \alpha(i)\right) \\
&\cong \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{C}}(Y, \varinjlim_{i \in \mathsf{I}} \alpha(i)).
\end{align}
On the third line, we interchanged the order of limits and colimits because **filtered colimits commute with finite limits in the category of sets.** (See post [About a specific step in a proof of the fact that filtered colimits and finite limits commute in $\mathbf{Set}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3075524/about-a-specific-step-in-a-proof-of-the-fact-that-filtered-colimits-and-finite-l) .) The fourth line holds since $X$ is **compact**.

However, the aobve process FAILED since in the completely compact case, we shall check for all *small* colimits, not just filtered ones. So the commutativity of "colimits" and "limits" failed. So how to *generalize* the proof to *completely compact* case, or are there any new proofs?

Any references are also welcome.

Thank you all for answering and commenting! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Retracts are stable under arbitrary functors. Deduce that $\mathrm{Hom}(Y,-)$ is a retract of a cocontinuous functor. Colimits of cocontinuous functors are cocontinuous.

Comment: Thank you so much for your hints! Now I got it. :)